# Display the dates between today and a day in the past

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following df:

```
data = {"Last check":['3/17/2017,'3/12/2020','3/2/2020','2/13/2018']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

What I'm trying to archive is to display only the date/dates between today and a day in the past calculated previously.

```
def TimeDelta():

    import datetime as dt
    global result, today
    today = dt.date.today()
    how_many = input("How many days: ")
    result = today - timedelta(days=int(how_many))
    print(result, today)

def W(filename):
    TimeDelta()
    data = #in example

    data['Last check']= pd.to_datetime(data['Last check'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
    print(result < data['Last check'] < today )
```

So, if today is 2020-03-27 and timedelta is set for 26 days ago(2020-03-01), the output should be:

```
3/12/2020
3/1/2020
```

And the **error**:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error is in the way you create your DataFrame.
The result of your code is that *Last check* column is of
*object* type (actually a *string*). To confirm this, run `df.info()`.

But you want to compare **dates**, so this column should be of any possible
**date** type.

Note also that *Pandas* has its **own** built-in datetime and timedelta types,
namely *datetime64* and *Timedelta*, so you don't need to use *datetime* package.

To create your DataFrame, run:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

In order to use *pandasonic* own *Timedelta* type, change
your *TimeDelta* function to:

```
def TimeDelta():
    global result, today
    today = pd.Timestamp.today().normalize()
    how_many = input("How many days: ")
    result = today - pd.Timedelta(how_many + 'D')
    print(result, today)
```

And to print *df* rows with *Last check* within the proper date range,
run:

```
print(df[df['Last check'].between(result, today)])
```

And the last detail: Since you created *df* with proper column type, remove

```
data['Last check']= pd.to_datetime(data['Last check'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

instruction from your *W* function.

Answer (score 0):

Try .loc[]

```
sub_data = data.loc[(data['Last check'] > result) and (data['Last check'] < today)]
```

Docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html